# Setting the content of an outgoing message fails

Tags: email, applescript

i tried to create an auto reply script but as soon as i try to set the content of the outgoing message it throws an error and tells me that "content" can't be read.

```
set replyMessage to reply thisMessage with opening window
delay 2
set rich text content of replyMessage to "Hallo"
```

any ideas?

edit: full code:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set replyList to {}
    set inboxMessages to every message in inbox

    # get Einsatz mail from all emails
    repeat with thisMessage in inboxMessages
        set thisContent to content of thisMessage
        set thisSender to sender of thisMessage

        if thisSender contains "@pos-lifestyle.de" then
            if thisContent contains "nochmal alle wichtigen Informationen zum Heimspiel" then
                if thisContent contains "deinen Einsatz per Mail" and thisContent contains "Bitte bestätige" then
                    set end of replyList to thisMessage
                    set read status of thisMessage to true
                end if
            end if
        end if
    end repeat


    # reply to all Einsatz mails
    repeat with thisMessage in replyList
        set replyMessage to reply thisMessage with opening window
        delay 2
        set content of replyMessage to (("Hallo," & return & "hiermit bestätige ich den Einsatz." & return & "Mit besten Grüßen" & return & "Max Mustermann") as rich text)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now complete the full script based on your latest update.
I tested it with several cases, and it is 100% working for me. I just made couple of simplifications.
Also, I have set the targets (sender and content) on top of the script to make it easier to read and test (to test , I just have to change values of 4 lines on top with possible values from my mail box !).

```
set TargetSend to "@pos-lifestyle.de"
set Target1 to "nochmal alle wichtigen Informationen zum Heimspiel"
set Target2 to "deinen Einsatz per Mail"
set Target3 to "Bitte bestätige"

tell application "Mail"
set replyList to {}
set inboxMessages to every message in inbox whose sender contains TargetSend
repeat with thisMessage in inboxMessages
    set thisContent to content of thisMessage
    if (thisContent contains Target1) and (thisContent contains Target2) and (thisContent contains Target3) then
        set end of replyList to thisMessage
        set read status of thisMessage to true
    end if
end repeat

# reply to all Einsatz mails
repeat with thisMessage in replyList
    set replyMessage to reply thisMessage with opening window
    delay 2
    set content of replyMessage to (("Hallo," & return & "hiermit bestätige ich den Einsatz." & return & "Mit besten Grüßen" & return & "Max Mustermann") as rich text)
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: thank you! Unfortunately this gets me an error as well: "content of item" cannot set to "any" number -10006 from content of item to any

Comment: it is working fine for me (yosemite / Mail 8.2). Of course I assume that your script is in a tell application "Mail" / end tell block.

Comment: thats odd, i posted the whole script above

Comment: error "„Mail“ hat einen Fehler erhalten: „content of item“ kann nicht als „any“ gesetzt werden." number -10006 from content of item to any... 

it's the same error as i mentioned earlier, this is strange. i'm on el capitan with Mail 9.1 btw

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to prevent this error from happening

```
set TargetSend to "@pos-lifestyle.de"
set Target1 to "nochmal alle wichtigen Informationen zum Heimspiel"
set Target2 to "deinen Einsatz per Mail"
set Target3 to "Bitte bestätige"
set MyName to "Max Musterman"

tell application "Mail"
    set replyList to {}
    set inboxMessages to every message in inbox whose sender contains TargetSend

    # look for Einsatz mails
    repeat with thisMessage in inboxMessages
        set thisContent to content of thisMessage
        if (thisContent contains Target1) and (thisContent contains Target2) and (thisContent contains Target3) then
            set end of replyList to thisMessage
            set read status of thisMessage to true
        end if
    end repeat

    # reply to all Einsatz mails
    repeat with thisMessage in replyList
        set replyMessage to reply thisMessage with opening window
        repeat until exists (window 1 whose name = "Re: " & subject of thisMessage)
        end repeat
        delay 0.1

        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Mail"
                set frontmost to true
                keystroke "Hallo"
                keystroke return
                keystroke "Hiermit bestätige ich den Einsatz."
                keystroke return
                keystroke "Mit besten Grüßen"
                keystroke return
                keystroke MyName
                keystroke return
            end tell
        end tell

        #send replyMessage

    end repeat
end tell
```